# Sonarcloud with Github Enterprise

Tags: sonarcloud

Have tried sonarcloud with public github repositories. But how do I go about integrating it with our enterprise github repos.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for the party, but I've been researching this and found out that SonarCloud is not meant to integrate with on-premise installations, as explained on [SonarSource](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/github-enterprise/1908).